# Traverse nested "forums" and count their "topics" with C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In PHPBB, the forum system, we have forums with topics, where each forum has many topics (one-to-many) and each forum can contain a sub-forums. The forums can be infinitely nested. For example.

```
- forum1 contains 0 topics, but has total 5 topics  
  -- forum1.1 contains 3 topic  
  -- forum1.2 contains 2 topic
```

For visual example, lets say we have the following forums.

`#forum1` has 0 own topics, but displays 5, counting all it's children topics

[image]

`#forum1.1` has 5 own topics

[image]

Now my problem is, how can I count the exact number of topics each sub-forum has, so that I can display it on top in forum1. I tried looking at PHPBB's code in GitHub, but I cant figure it out. However I do see that they don't even keep topics counter as a field in the forum entity, in their database, they somehow aggregate all forums with a code/query, count their topics and return the number. How's that possible exactly?

I want to achieve this with C# + EF Core. However how can I traverse each sub-forum, when EF Core requires me to explicitly state how much deep I want to go, when instead I want to go as deep as possible, until there are no children left. As if I'm trying to hit a bottom of recursion. Is this possible?

For example this code:

```
List<Forum> forums = this.dbContext.Forums
.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue)
.Select(x => new Forum
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,           
    Children = x.Children.Select(c => new Forum
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        Description = x.Description,
    })
    .ToList()       
})
.ToList();
```

Returns

```
Forum1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "The Lore"
    children: [
        Forum2: {id: 2, name: "This Wretched World"},
        Forum3: {id: 3, name: "Test test test"}
    ]
}
```

But if I want to keep drilling down, I have to type it out manually and then figure out how to count. Now I'm not sure if I should be doing a while(true) instead and sending queries in some kind of a DFS manner, then calculating the total topics to display on top (this seems slow), but I'm running out of ideas here. Also what really bothers me is that if no one tell me how they did it back then, I will definitely never learn how it's done. I really hope, somebody has an idea or knows how those forum systems are build.

Comment: Just to clarify, a "dilemma" is a choice between two equally good or bad options. You seem to just want to know how to do something, so you have a "problem", not a "dilemma".

Comment: Better to do that with SQL using Recursive CTE. Goggle it, SO has a lot of answers.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks! I will check Recursive CTE right away, didn't knew this existed, but I feel it's going to be slow? Maybe there is a better approach to aggregate the data?

Comment: As i know it is best solution for hierarchical data analysis. For sure if database has no other support.